# Hide Image When Anchor HREF Source Is Not Present

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I would like to poll an anchor's href source about once every 5 seconds, to see whether a file at that address is present. When it is present, display an image in the anchor. In other words, the link is basically not there unless the file is present.

I'm guessing I would have to poll using an http HEAD request to determine whether the file exists, then toggle the image appropriately. Once the file has been determined to exist, I can stop polling and leave the image visible.

Is there a better way to do this, and can anyone suggest some script that would handle this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is configured to do so you can use:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

To poll for the file's existence by using the statusCode map

```
function checkFile() {
    $.ajax({
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                //file does not yet exist
                setTimeout(checkFile, 5000);
            }
            200: function() {
                //file exists.
                showImage();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You may want to capture a few more edge cases though, (for example, an error callback).

Comment: If I understand the AJAX functionality correctly, I believe using this would be the most appropriate solution. I do not want to download the file, just check to see that it exists. These are not the link icons. They are very large PDF's which are being generated on-the-fly in about two to four minutes. That's why I don't want to show the link until they are ready. If I can obtain the status code without downloading the file, that's an ideal solution.

Comment: In that case you are going to want to make sure you add 

type: 'HEAD'

to the anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

// note, this piece of code assumes to be using jQuery

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   var _el=$('#hrefId');
   var href = _el.attr('href');
   if(href == null || typeof href == 'undefined' || href == '')
      return;

   ajax call to href(in case on ur server(!) )

   // on success
   _el.attr('href','TheLink');
   $('img', _el).show(); // show image
}, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a socket library so the server can push a notification when the image is ready. socket.io seems like a good options here.

Another way would be to listen for the `error` event on the image, then wait for x milliseconds before trying to load it again. This is quite easy to implement, because every time you define a src attribute, the browser will add new listeners.

It’s basically the same as your meta-description but you don’t need to use ajax. You will also be able to load images from other domains (ajax have a cross-site policy):

```
var img = new Image(),
    src = '/path/to/image.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    console.log('loaded', img);
};
img.onerror = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        img.src = src;
    },500);
};
img.src = src;​
```

**Here is a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/L2L3U/**. The program will try to load a 404 image for three seconds, after that I change the src to a real image and it will display it.

Comment: I'll probably wait until SignalR gets a little more mature before I try this.  :) 

I do not want to load anything. I simply want to test for the existence of a file at the corresponding address.

Comment: OK I misunderstood, I was under the impression that we where talking about images only...